How to check for an item not in an object
I have some borrowed code I'm trying to tweak for my needs. Ref. below code:
// Object that will contain all of the MRNs we want to keep
var assgnAuthToKeep = {};

for each(pid3 in PIDsegment['PID.3']) {
  if (pid3['PID.3.4'].toString() in assgnAuthToKeep) {
    delete PIDsegment[pid3.childIndex];
  }
}

How can I check for the value NOT IN the object in the if statement?
!in doesn't work nor does not in

Perhaps you are looking for Object.hasOwnProperty()?

if (!(a in b)), for the generic case of inverting boolean expressions based on keywords (e.g. instanceof)

for each(...) is not valid syntax in javascript, and someString in someOtherString is not valid in javascript, for that you would do someOtherString.includes(someString) and then to invert that condition just add a ! at the beginning

@Samathingamajig someString in someObject is perfectly valid javascript though, which the OP is doing (and is really the thrust of the question)

Like how Rogue mentioned you can invert the boolean expression. Here is your block of code using that method instead:
var assgnAuthToKeep = {};

for each(pid3 in PIDsegment['PID.3']) {
    let pid3 = PIDsegment['PID.3'][i];
    let pid34Value = pid3['PID.3.4'].toString();

    if (!(pid34Value in assgnAuthToKeep)) {
        delete PIDsegment[pid3.childIndex];
    }
}


I have a few questions:

What do your data structures look like?

What does PIDsegment look like?
Is assgnAuthToKeep a Set, a Map, or an Object?


I am not sure what the point of the childIndex is.

From what I can infer, it looks like you want to use for..of instead of for..in, if you want to access a key on a value.


// Object that will contain all of the MRNs we want to keep
var assgnAuthToKeep = new Set(['FOO', 'BAR']);

const PIDsegment = {
  'PID.3': [
    { 'PID.3.4': 'FOO', childIndex: 0 },
    { 'PID.3.4': 'BAR', childIndex: 1 },
    { 'PID.3.4': 'BAZ', childIndex: 2 },
  ]
};

for (let pid3 of PIDsegment['PID.3']) {
  const assgnAuth = pid3['PID.3.4']?.toString();
  if (assgnAuthToKeep.has(assgnAuth)) continue;
  console.log('Removing:', assgnAuth, pid3.childIndex);
  //delete PIDsegment[pid3.childIndex];
}




The !in operator is a valid way to check if a value is not in an object. However, the syntax in your code is incorrect. You need to use the ! operator before the in operator, not after.
var assgnAuthToKeep = {};

for ( var pid3 in PIDsegment['PID.3'] )

{
    
if ( ! ( pid3['PID.3.4'].toString() in assgnAuthToKeep ) )

 {
       
 delete PIDsegment[pid3.childIndex];

    
}

}


!in isn't an operator, rather in and ! are separate operators. a in b is a boolean expression (and in is a binary operator), so invoking it produces a boolean value (true/false). You can use ! after the fact on the whole expression to negate it, hence !(a in b).

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
